# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demoRestController'

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and I am try to make a application for learning but I am getting problem in Autowiring,I am adding my code. I am working on spring boot.

Spring Boot Code

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

LoginBean.java

```
@Service
@Component
public class LoginBean {
    private String userId;
    private String pwd;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }
```

DemoRestController.java

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/demo")
@Component
public class DemoRestController {


    private final LoginBean loginBean;

    @Autowired
    public DemoRestController(LoginBean loginBean) {
        this.loginBean=loginBean;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/{id},{pwd}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody LoginBean loginService(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String pwd) {
        //LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();

        loginBean.setUserId(id);
        loginBean.setPwd(pwd);
        return loginBean;
    }
```

I tried following scenarios to make my @Autowired work:

1. @Autowired to LoginBean loginBean;
2. Created getter setter of LoginBean in Controller class and autowired setters;
3. Created constructor of Controller and autowired, as given in above code;

Below is the error which I am getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demoRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.ag.digital.demo.bean.LoginBean]: No qualifying bean of type [com.ag.digital.demo.bean.LoginBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ag.digital.demo.bean.LoginBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ag.digital.demo.boot.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ag.digital.demo.bean.LoginBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Hi I have solved my issue. @Andy Thank you so much for your valuable response. I am sorry I should have provided my SpringBoot's Application class also. Actually the main problem was in Spring Boot's Application Class. I am providing Code. 
public class DemoApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }
} The class name and parameter class name should be same and this was my actual problem.

Comment: ,What is parameter class name

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Your `DemoApplication` class is in the `com.ag.digital.demo.boot` package and your `LoginBean` class is in the `com.ag.digital.demo.bean` package. By default components (classes annotated with `@Component`) are found if they are in the same package or a sub-package of your main application class `DemoApplication`. This means that `LoginBean` isn't being found so dependency injection fails.

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem:

1. Move `LoginBean` into `com.ag.digital.demo.boot` or a sub-package.
2. Configure the packages that are scanned for components using the `scanBasePackages` attribute of `@SpringBootApplication` that should be on `DemoApplication`.

A few of other things that aren't causing a problem, but are not quite right with the code you've posted:

- `@Service` is a specialisation of `@Component` so you don't need both on `LoginBean`
- Similarly, `@RestController` is a specialisation of `@Component` so you don't need both on `DemoRestController`
- `DemoRestController` is an unusual place for `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. That annotation is typically found on your main application class (`DemoApplication`) either directly or via `@SpringBootApplication` which is a combination of `@ComponentScan`, `@Configuration`, and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Answer (score 2):

To me it happened in `DogController` that autowired `DogService` that autowired `DogRepository`. `Dog` class used to have field `name` but I changed it to `coolName`, but didn't change methods in `DogRepository`: `Dog findDogByName(String name)`. I change that method to `Dog findDogByCoolName(String name)` and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this is erroring out during my unit test, apparently, not only do I have to add the new package on the Main class, but also on the Test configuration class where in the ComponentScan annotation specific to the test classes, I just added

```
com.bpg.csp.cbs.common.util
```

since this is the new package I added on my project. A snippet of my full test configuration code is below

```
@Profile("junit")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.bpg.services.booking.gds.adapter.impl.config",
        "com.bpg.csp.cbs.common.util"
})
public class TestConfiguration
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My case, in my repository class I used to below function:

`List<WishList> findAllByUserOrderByCreatedDateDesending(User user);`

I change the function name to     `List<WishList> findAllByUserOrderByCreatedDateDesc(User user);` and It works

Comment: This worked because you were using wrong method name. I think, if you use good IDE, it will suggest you while you're writing codes.