# How to search database for string instead id with findById()?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, findby

how can I search for a string Pathvariable instead of a Integer by ID? I like to find the names.

The method below works well, but just with IDs as a Integer value.

Thanks :)

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/etbestandservice")
public class ETBestandserviceController {

    @Autowired
    ETBestandserviceRepository etbestandRepos;

        @GetMapping(value = "/find/{id}", produces = "application/json")
        public Optional<ETBestandservice> findErsatzteile(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ETBestandservice et) {

        id = et.getId();
        return etbestandRepos.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a little?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `Optional<ETBestandservice> findByName(String name)` method in your Spring JPA `ETBestandserviceRepository` interface and Spring will generate the expected query for you for that at startup.
If the query may return several results, replace `Optional<ETBestandservice>` by `List<ETBestandservice>`.
More information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details).

Comment: I had already try that, but it doesn't work for me. I get this Exception: UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ETBestandserviceController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'etbestandRepos';

Comment: this exception does have anything to do with query @volkanb

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214538/org-springframework-beans-factory-unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating @volkanb