# Getting error "No Qualifying bean of type available " with maven build of a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have written a Restful application in springboot.
So for that i have a controller class with @RestController and a service class with @Service annotation.
In my Rest controller, i @Autowire the service like below.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowire
    TestService testService;
}  

@Service
public class TestService {
}
```

Note : My main springboot class at top level of all the packages.

The strange thing is that, when i start my Spring boot application, it start perfectly and service bean initalized correctly. I also tested the same. But when i do maven build it gets failed with error :

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'TestService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Please show the code of your test

Comment: Test classes are dummy names in my example. Its business code which i can't share. Any specific thing which you would like know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214538/org-springframework-beans-factory-unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating

see this.

Comment: And how does your package structure look like? Where is the SpringBootApplication class?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli As i mentioned in question itself, my spring boot class is at root level, above all my packages where my classes exist. I am able to start my springboot application successfully in IntelliJ and able to test my Rest service end to end. The problem happens only when i do maven build.

Comment: @krishnkantjaiswal It doesn't answer my problem. Everything is configured as per rule of Springboot application.

Comment: Where does it fail in the maven build? In test phase?

Comment: Yes, in test phase. Just an FYI right now there is no test cases written for this Rest service. There are test cases we have for other implementations. But yes, its failing in test phase.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Do you have any clue related to failing in test phase?

Comment: because it tries to start SpringBoot in during the tests

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes we have written SpringBootTests for some tesing. So any solution you would recommend.

Comment: And if you run one of them in the IDE it works?

Comment: Finally, the issue has resolved. The problem was, someone missed to provide the controller class in @WebMvcTest annotation in controller test class. So after making this change the issue has resolved. @WebMvcTest(<controller-class-name>.class). Don't know how does impact this to other beans initialization  but it fixed the issue and its worthy to keep it mind and can help others if facing the same kind of issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for looking into this issue and your suggestions.