# Is this a problem related to the configuration of mongodb inside my file (application.properties)?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

To my fellow developers,

Ambiguous errors logs without clear indication of which files went wrong are perhaps some of the most troublesome bugs. I am a complete newb playing with java spring. Below is the error I encountered when I try to run my public class SpringWithMongodbApplication.

I have made sure the credentials inside application.properties is correct. By the way, looking up similar errors, I have found the error log inside terminal is unique from other posts. PLS help <3

**ERROR INSIDE TERMINAL:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootTutorialApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'groceryItemRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository' defined in com.example.springboottutorial.repository.ItemRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on SpringBootTutorialApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up TXT record for host cluster0.mongodb.net
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
```

**CODE INSIDE SpringWithMongodbApplication:**

```
package com.example.springboottutorial;

import com.example.springboottutorial.model.GroceryItem;
import com.example.springboottutorial.repository.CustomItemRepository;
import com.example.springboottutorial.repository.ItemRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class SpringBootTutorialApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ItemRepository groceryItemRepo;

    @Autowired
    CustomItemRepository customRepo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTutorialApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println("--------------CREATE GROCERY ITEMS------------------");
        createGroceryItems();
        System.out.println("\n----------------SHOW ALL GROCERY ITEMS---------------------------\n");

        showAllGroceryItems();

        System.out.println("\n--------------GET ITEM BY NAME-----------------------------------\n");

        getGroceryItemByName("Whole Wheat Biscuit");

        System.out.println("\n-----------GET ITEMS BY CATEGORY---------------------------------\n");

        getItemsByCategory("millets");

        System.out.println("\n-----------UPDATE CATEGORY NAME OF SNACKS CATEGORY----------------\n");

        updateCategoryName("snacks");

        System.out.println("\n----------DELETE A GROCERY ITEM----------------------------------\n");

        deleteGroceryItem("Kodo Millet");

        System.out.println("\n------------FINAL COUNT OF GROCERY ITEMS-------------------------\n");

        findCountOfGroceryItems();

        System.out.println("\n-------------------THANK YOU---------------------------");

        System.out.println("\n-----------UPDATE QUANTITY OF A GROCERY ITEM------------------------\n");

        updateItemQuantity("Bonny Cheese Crackers Plain", 10);
    }

    void createGroceryItems() {
        System.out.println("Data creation started...");
        groceryItemRepo.save(new GroceryItem("Whole Wheat Biscuit", "Whole Wheat Biscuit", 5, "snacks"));
        groceryItemRepo.save(new GroceryItem("Kodo Millet", "XYZ Kodo Millet healthy", 2, "millets"));
        groceryItemRepo.save(new GroceryItem("Dried Red Chilli", "Dried Whole Red Chilli", 2, "spices"));
        groceryItemRepo.save(new GroceryItem("Pearl Millet", "Healthy Pearl Millet", 1, "millets"));
        groceryItemRepo.save(new GroceryItem("Cheese Crackers", "Bonny Cheese Crackers Plain", 6, "snacks"));
        groceryItemRepo.save(new GroceryItem("Chocolate Candies", "Maltesers", 3, "sweets"));
        groceryItemRepo.save(new GroceryItem("Squid Slices", "Four Islands", 6, "snacks"));
        System.out.println("Data creation complete...");
    }

    //show all data
    public void showAllGroceryItems() {
        groceryItemRepo.findAll().forEach(item -> System.out.println(getItemDetails(item)) );
    }

//  Get item by name
    public void getGroceryItemByName(String name) {
        System.out.println("getting item by name: " + name);
        GroceryItem item = groceryItemRepo.findItemByName(name);
        System.out.println(getItemDetails(item));
    }

//  get name and quantiy of all item of a particular category
    public void getItemsByCategory(String category) {
        System.out.println("Getting items for the category" + category);
        List<GroceryItem> list = groceryItemRepo.findAll(category);

        list.forEach(item -> System.out.println("Name: " + item.getName() + ", Quantity: " + item.getQuantity()));
    }
    public void findCountOfGroceryItems() {
        long count = groceryItemRepo.count();
        System.out.println("Number of documents in the collection: " + count);
    }
    public String getItemDetails(GroceryItem item) {
        System.out.println(
                "Item Name: " + item.getName() +
                        ", \nQuantity: " + item.getQuantity() +
                        ", \nItem Category: " + item.getCategory()
        );
        return "";
    }
    public void updateCategoryName(String category) {
        //new value
        String newCategory = "munchies";

//      List all items with category snacks
        List<GroceryItem> list = groceryItemRepo.findAll(category);

        list.forEach(item -> {
            //Update the category in each document
            item.setCategory(newCategory);
        });

        //Save all the items in the databse
        List<GroceryItem> itemsUpdated = groceryItemRepo.saveAll(list);

        if(itemsUpdated != null)
            System.out.println("Successfully updated " + itemsUpdated.size() + " items.");
    }

    //DELETE
        public void deleteGroceryItem(String id) {
        groceryItemRepo.deleteById(id);
            System.out.println("Item with id " + id + " deleted...");
        }
        public void deleteAllGroceryItems() {
        groceryItemRepo.deleteAll();
            System.out.println("All items inside Grocery deleted");
        }
    //UPDATE
        public void updateItemQuantity(String name, float newQuantity) {
            System.out.println("Updating quantity for " + name);
            customRepo.updateItemQuantity(name, newQuantity);
        }
}
```

**CODE INSIDE ItemRepository**:

```
package com.example.springboottutorial.repository;

import com.example.springboottutorial.model.GroceryItem;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<GroceryItem, String> {

    @Query("{name: '?0'}")
    GroceryItem findItemByName(String name);

    @Query(value="{category:'?0'}", fields="{'name' : 1, 'quantity' : 1}")
    List<GroceryItem> findAll (String category);

    public long count();


}
```

**CODE INSIDE CustomItemRepositoryImpl**:

```
package com.example.springboottutorial.repository;

import com.example.springboottutorial.model.GroceryItem;
import com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

public class CustomItemRepositoryImpl implements CustomItemRepository{
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public void updateItemQuantity(String name, float newQuantity) {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is(name));
        Update update = new Update();
        update.set("quantity", newQuantity);

        UpdateResult result = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, GroceryItem.class);

        if(result == null)
            System.out.println("No documents updated");
        else
            System.out.println(result.getModifiedCount() + " documents(s) updated..");
    }

}
```

**CODE INSIDE CustomItemRepository**:

```
package com.example.springboottutorial.repository;

public interface CustomItemRepository {
    void updateItemQuantity(String name, float newQuantity);

}
```

**CODE INSIDE GroceryItem**:

```
package com.example.springboottutorial.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document("groceryitems")
public class GroceryItem {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private String category;

    public GroceryItem(String id, String name, int quantity, String category) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String newCategory) {
        this.category = newCategory;
    }

//    public void getName(String name) {
//        this.name = name;
//    }
}
```

**CODE INSIDE application.properties**:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://reactmaster123:react8927@cluster0.mongodb.net/mygrocerylist
spring.data.mongodb.database=mygrocerylist
```

ScreenShot of file structure:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdDbe.png

Comment: See this SO post for clues: [org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demoRestController'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214538/org-springframework-beans-factory-unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating)

Comment: Also could you put the stacktrace into a code block for improved readability?

Comment: I checked m public void main method. What I have inside is correct. But it seems something related to SpringBootTutorialApplication.class