# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderController' error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

> Hi I'm new to SpringBoot and I keep getting this error when I try to
> run the
> application along with " Exception encountered during context initialization -
> cancelling refresh attempt". This is my controller class(orderController)

```
`package com.example.demo.controller;

 import com.example.demo.model.Order;
 import com.example.demo.repository.OrderRepository;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


 import java.util.List;

 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("api/")
 public class OrderController {

@Autowired
private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

public OrderController(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
    this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
}

@GetMapping("/Order")
public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> getAllOrders() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.orderRepository.findAll());

}
@PostMapping("/Order")
public ResponseEntity<Order> createOrders(@RequestBody Order orderRequest) {
    Order order=new Order();
    order.setId(orderRequest.getId());
    order.setSellerId(orderRequest.getSellerId());
    order.setAddress(orderRequest.getAddress());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.orderRepository.save(order));

}
```

}

`

Comment: Sounds like issue is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214538/org-springframework-beans-factory-unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating). If that's not it, include complete stacktrace, you should have done so from the start...

Comment: As a side note, you should put `@Autowired` on the constructor, not the field, when using constructor injection.

Comment: Is your controller's class name `OrderController` or `orderController`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the @Autowired annotation at the field and add at the constructor level.

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

 import com.example.demo.model.Order;
 import com.example.demo.repository.OrderRepository;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


 import java.util.List;

 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("api/")
 public class OrderController {

//@Autowired -remove from here
private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

@Autowired // add here
public OrderController(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
    this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
}

@GetMapping("/Order")
public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> getAllOrders() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.orderRepository.findAll());

}
@PostMapping("/Order")
public ResponseEntity<Order> createOrders(@RequestBody Order orderRequest) {
    Order order=new Order();
    order.setId(orderRequest.getId());
    order.setSellerId(orderRequest.getSellerId());
    order.setAddress(orderRequest.getAddress());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.orderRepository.save(order));

}
```

This should work

Answer (score -1):

you can use the dependency called Lombok... very useful:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>{Version what you need}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Lombok will create with this annotation a constuctor by picking just the final fields.

you can do after adding this:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderController {


  private final OrderRepository orderRepository;


  @GetMapping("/Order")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> getAllOrders() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.orderRepository.findAll());

  }

  @PostMapping("/Order")
  public ResponseEntity<Order> createOrders(@RequestBody Order 
  orderRequest) {
     Order order=new Order();
     order.setId(orderRequest.getId());
     order.setSellerId(orderRequest.getSellerId());
     order.setAddress(orderRequest.getAddress());

     return ResponseEntity.ok(this.orderRepository.save(order));

  }}
```

Comment: OP already has defined a constructor. How does lombok even help with unsatisfied dependency issue?